# How to clear ALL cache, including field and filter caching of nodes and fields?

Tags: 7, caching

I'm working on a text format filter module. Now, somehow Drupal keeps the node content in some cache that is not refreshed with `drush cc all`, which I would have hoped to "clear all cache". This is with *Cache pages for anonymous users* and *Cache blocks* disabled.

I wrote a little script that adds `" "` at the end of the node body, but even running that between two `drush cc all`s doesn't cut it, still with cache disabled.
It's really strange. If I go to a page I haven't accessed yet, it will show me an old version what was filtered.  So I'm tempted to now also let the script access the specific node over HTTP...

Is there an easy way to really clear all cache? I guess dropping and recreating all `cache_*` tables could cut it but that seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking at a wrong cache? I don't think it's node related. Perhaps field cache, or filter cache. What did you define for `cache` for your filter's [`hook_filter_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7)? It defaults to TRUE.

Comment: Doesn't `drush cc all` clear all cache?

Comment: I've tried looking for that info, but have been unsuccessful. It may not clear field or filter cache. Running `drush cc` gives you the following options: 1) All 2) Drush 3) Theme Registry 4) Menu 5) CSS-JS 6) Block 7) Module List 8) Theme List 9) Registry. If Option 1 (all) only clears the items 2-9 then it won't clear field or filter cache. I don't really know 100% how drush works or if it's this or something completely different that's causing your issue! Just trying to help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what's the "correct" way to do this. But you could try temporarily changing the configuration of the text format, e.g. by enabling an extra filter. I think to remember that this will trigger a recalculation of the filtered text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"All" cache doesn't include the filter cache and if you are working with filters then that's the one you most likely want to clear.

You can clear the filter cache by truncating the `cache_filter` database table.

If you have drush at your disposal, you can run `drush sqlq "truncate table cache_filter;"` to get the intended result.

Please note, if you are using database prefixing you will need to add the prefix yourself, as the `drush sql-query` command executes the query exactly as provided.

Comment: Thanks for this! Quite crazy that `drush cc all` doesn't actually clear `all` cache.